# Ruby Newbie Needs to Convert a String to Byte Array with Some Padding

Tags: ruby

in Ruby I have a string like this:

myString = "mystring"

I want to convert the string to a byte array taking only the first 16 bytes and pad with 0's if shorter.

I can do this the brute force way.  But...

Care to share a 'cool' way?

Comment: Please show the desired result for your example (by editing). To format code, indent four spaces or select the code and click on indent icon.

Comment: Wow, what a title

Comment: "I want to convert the string to a byte array taking only the first 16 bytes and pad with 0's if shorter." – Then do it! We're not stopping you. You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: Also, please give a precise, objective, measurable, verifiable definition of "cool".

Comment: Mr. Mittag.  I explained EXACTLY what I wanted to do.  Your comments are unconstructive and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? You should probably check for edge cases like multibyte chars.

```
"my string"[0..15].ljust(16,'0')
```

Comment: Aza.  You give me the closest that I wanted.  In the end, I ended up implementing:    ba = name[0..15].ljust(16, "\0").bytes.to_a

Comment: Oh.  By the way.  I'm not worried about "multibyte chars".  There are no edge cases...I think...unless the substring [0..15] is taking characters (integers).  The problem statement is "take the first 16 bytes"..  I am only interested in bytes.  but, nevertheless, your answer gave me what I needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the string as a byte array by calling [`bytes`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-bytes) on it, then once you have it as a byte array, you can [`take`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-take) the first 16 elements. Finally, you pad the array by [`fill`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-fill)ing it with a range as the second argument:

```
def padded_byte_array(string, length = 16)
  bytes = string.bytes.take(length)

  bytes.fill(0, bytes.length...length)
end
```

and then you can call it:

```
padded_byte_array('my string')
# => [109, 121, 32, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
padded_byte_array('some super long string longer than 16 bytes')
# => [115, 111, 109, 101, 32, 115, 117, 112, 101, 114, 32, 108, 111, 110, 103, 32]
padded_byte_array('本当に長いマルチバイト文字列')
# => [230, 156, 172, 229, 189, 147, 227, 129, 171, 233, 149, 183, 227, 129, 132, 227]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that if `arr.size < str.size`, where `str` is the string and `arr` is the array to be returned, `str.bytes` is returned. If, in that case, `str.bytes[0, [str.size, arr.size].min]` is to be returned, that requires an obvious adjustment.

```
def padded_bytes(str, arr_size)
  str_bytes = str.bytes
  Array.new([arr_size, str.size].max) { |i| str_bytes.fetch(i, 0) }
end

padded_bytes("tiger", 8)
  #=> [116, 105, 103, 101, 114, 0, 0, 0]
padded_bytes("tiger", 3)
  #=> [116, 105, 103, 101, 114]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks for your answers.

In the end, I implemented

```
ba = name[0..15].ljust(16, "\0").bytes.to_a
```

Aza gave the closest to what I asked.

My original looked like this:

```
ba = name[0..15].bytes.to_a
while ba.length < 16 do ba.push(0) end
```

Until I got your answers.  Thanks again!